# How to make a auto counter to print pages

Tags: excel, vba, automation, counter

I have two macros one to sort the excel sheet by account number and one to print the page and put a pdf in a folder the first macro that sorts it needs a reference in a cell that goes based off account number witch we have them as F01 0001 to F01 2000 then F02 all the way to F14 is there a way to make the cell go F01 0001 then sort then print then go F01 0002 automatically and loop the processes till its done

```
Sub Automake()
    For Each r In Range("E8")
        r.Value = r.Value + 1
        run filter e by e:8
        run produceinv
    Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through all of those account numbers:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Filter_And_Sum()

    Dim lPrefix As Long
    Dim lCount As Long
    Dim Account_Number As String
    
    For lPrefix = 1 To 14
        For lCount = 1 To 2000
            Account_Number = "F" & Format(lPrefix, "00") & " " & Format(lCount, "0000")
            Debug.Print Account_Number
            
            ' Do something ...
            
        Next lCount
    Next lPrefix
    
End Sub
```

Output:
[image] [image]